# GoogleAPIS for Firebase Admin Auth SDK

Tags: firebase, dart, google-api

I am building a backend server using `dart`.

Since there isn't any `firebase admin sdk` for `dart`, I am using `GoogleAPIS` in order to interact with the `firebase`.

For the `firebase authentication`, I see that it is same as `Identity Platform` in Google Cloud.

From the list of `googleAPIS` ([Link](https://pub.dev/documentation/googleapis/latest/)), which api is the one that acts like `firebase admin auth SDk`? so that I can perform api calls such as change the user's verification status?

Thanks for the help!